# How to handle the positions in Gallery android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

How to handle the positions in Gallery.I need to change the background of image at perticular position.Iam able to change the background image of selected image successfully within the onItemClick method.But i need to change the old selected background image also as non-selected one.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        //previouse selected image  
//here sometimes it is changing background of another image(which is not a old selected image)  
        if(mSelectedItemIndex!=-1 && mSelectedItemIndex!=position){ 

//              Object v =mGallery.getItemAtPosition(mSelectedItemIndex);
//              View v =imageAdapter.getDropDownView(mSelectedItemIndex,null,null);
//          View v =mGallery.getChildAt(mSelectedItemIndex);
                View v = (View)view.getChildAt(mSelectedItemIndex);
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.adsimage);
//          ImageView imgView = (ImageView)v;

//          ImageView imgView = (ImageView)arg0.findViewById(R.id.adsimage);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallery_unselected_default);
//current selected image
//always this code is working fine.
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adsimage);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallery_selected_focused);
}
```

I used getItemBackground theme in base adapter but no use.Please give me how to persist image positions if gallery is scrolling form left to right and right to left.If i select one by one it is working fine.But when i select alternate image.It is not working.

Comment: I think it could make sense to not start a new post for every part of your issue but to stick with the original one.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.But no where iam getting correct answer.May be i couldn't represent clearly my question on previous posts.That's why I posted new one clearly.I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a member variable eg `View lastSelected` in your activity to store the view when it has been selected/clicked.  When a new item is selected/clicked use `lastSelected` to change the background and then update `lastSelected` with the newly selected view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I tried in many ways but why I don't try like this way i don't know.It is working fine.